# Javascript function is not defined on click event

Tags: javascript

EDIT: I have made a [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/891sygh4/) with the answer that still returns undefined function.

I am struggling to find out why my function is returning undefined. 
My html:

```
<div class="slideshow">
            <div class="slide">  
                <div class="work-info col-3">
                    <div class="block-orange">
                        <h3>Work</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi ipsum iure esse nemo facere ea, iste deserunt odit provident labore exercitationem nihil, laborum, sit vel nostrum illo ducimus possimus dolorum.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
            </div>

            <div class="dot-cont">
              <div class="dot" onclick="clickChangeSlide(0)"></div>
              <div class="dot" onclick="clickChangeSlide(1)"></div>
              <div class="dot" onclick="clickChangeSlide(2)"></div>
              <div class="dot" onclick="clickChangeSlide(3)"></div>
            </div>
            <button class="arrow-button left-arrow" onclick="clickChangeSlide(i-1)">&#60;</button>
            <button class="arrow-button right-arrow" onclick="clickChangeSlide(i+1)">&#62;</button>      
    </div>
```

The  js is being loaded at the bottom of the page. JS:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  let i = -1;
  let time = 5000;
  let slideTimer;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName('slide');
  let slideDots = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');

  function clickChangeSlide(n){
    clearTimeout(slideTimer);
    changeSlide(n, true);
  }

  function changeSlide(n = i, manual = false){

    for(let j = 0; j < slides.length; j++){
      if(j == i) {
        slides[j].classList.add('prev-slide');
        slides[j].classList.remove('active-slide');
        slideDots[j].classList.remove('active-dot');
        continue; 
      }
      slideDots[j].classList.remove('active-dot');
      slides[j].classList.remove('prev-slide'); 
      slides[j].classList.remove('active-slide');
    }
    if(manual){
      if(n < 0) i = slides.length - 1
      else if(n > slides.length - 1) i = 0
      else i = n
    }else i = i < slides.length - 1 ? i+1 : 0;

    slides[i].classList.add('active-slide');
    slideDots[i].classList.add('active-dot');

    slideTimer = setTimeout(changeSlide, time);
  }

  window.onload = changeSlide();
});
```

I tried to remove the DomcontentLoaded, as I thought this maybe effecting it but to no prevail. When I click the button, ClickChangeSlide does not fire. 
Any ideas?

Comment: The `clickChangeSlide()` function is defined *inside* that other event handler, so it is not visible in the global scope. You can bind the function as an event handler using `addEventListener()` instead of inline `onclick` attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DOM tries to access functions that aren't available at DOM build time, `onclick=clickChangeSlide(0)...` is responsible for that. Put both functions `changeSlide(...)` and `clickChangeSlide(...)` outside, of your actual `DOMContentLoaded` event listener to access these functions during DOM build time.

It could look like this:

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <div class="slide">  
        <div class="work-info col-3">
            <div class="block-orange">
                <h3>Work</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="dot-cont">
         <div class="dot" onclick="clickChangeSlide(0)"></div>
         <div class="dot" onclick="clickChangeSlide(1)"></div>
         <div class="dot" onclick="clickChangeSlide(2)"></div>
         <div class="dot" onclick="clickChangeSlide(3)"></div>
    </div>
    <button class="arrow-button left-arrow" onclick="clickChangeSlide(i-1)">&#60;</button>
    <button class="arrow-button right-arrow" onclick="clickChangeSlide(i+1)">&#62;</button>
</div>
```

Your javascript code should look like this:

```
let i = -1;
var slideTimer;
let time = 5000;
let slides = document.getElementsByClassName('slide');
let slideDots = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');

function changeSlide(n = i, manual = false) {
    for (let j = 0; j < slides.length; j++) {
        if (j == i) {
            slides[j].classList.add('prev-slide');
            slides[j].classList.remove('active-slide');
            slideDots[j].classList.remove('active-dot');
            continue; 
        }
        slideDots[j].classList.remove('active-dot');
        slides[j].classList.remove('prev-slide'); 
        slides[j].classList.remove('active-slide');
    }
    if (manual) {
        if(n < 0) i = slides.length - 1
        else if(n > slides.length - 1) i = 0
        else i = n
    } else i = i < slides.length - 1 ? i+1 : 0;

    slides[i].classList.add('active-slide');
    slideDots[i].classList.add('active-dot');

    slideTimer = setTimeout(changeSlide, time);
};

function clickChangeSlide(n) {
    clearTimeout(slideTimer);
    changeSlide(n, true);
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    window.onload = changeSlide();
});
```

You also have to change the scope of your variables `i, slides, slideDots, ...` because you access `changeSlide` before your variables were declared.
Load you javascript code at the top of you html code, with `<script src="javascript.js"></script>`, otherwise your DOM is not able intialize any function to the `onload` function of your div elements.

Comment: Is your javascript file loaded at the beginning of your html code?

Comment: I found out that it is actually to do with webpack and how it is compiling my code, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `clickChangeSlide()` inside the callback so it's scope does not exist throughout the document.

you have to define it outside the callback like:

```
let i = -1;
let time = 5000;
let slideTimer;
let slides = document.getElementsByClassName('slide');
let slideDots = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');    
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
window.onload = changeSlide();
});

function clickChangeSlide(n){
    clearTimeout(slideTimer);
    changeSlide(n, true);
  }

  function changeSlide(n = i, manual = false){

    for(let j = 0; j < slides.length; j++){
      if(j == i) {
        slides[j].classList.add('prev-slide');
        slides[j].classList.remove('active-slide');
        slideDots[j].classList.remove('active-dot');
        continue; 
      }
      slideDots[j].classList.remove('active-dot');
      slides[j].classList.remove('prev-slide'); 
      slides[j].classList.remove('active-slide');
    }
    if(manual){
      if(n < 0) i = slides.length - 1
      else if(n > slides.length - 1) i = 0
      else i = n
    }else i = i < slides.length - 1 ? i+1 : 0;

    slides[i].classList.add('active-slide');
    slideDots[i].classList.add('active-dot');

    slideTimer = setTimeout(changeSlide, time);
  }
```

Comment: I have tried this, I still get clickChangeSlide() undefined. If I was to do this approach I would also have to move the variables into the global scope too.

Comment: make sure you have included the <script> tag

Comment: I am still getting undefined.

Comment: if i console.log(clickchangeslide) I get a function so surely that means its available in global scope